# angularjs controller not binding to partial view

Tags: angularjs, controller, partial-views

One of the two controllers (AboutCtrl) defined is working as expected. The default controller, TransactionCtrl is paired with the correct partial view but there isn't any angularjs magic happening. For example, I have a simple expression 1 + 2 = {{ 1+2}} that is not resolving (displays as written).

Here's the app definition:

```
angular.module('pennyWatch', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    return $routeProvider
        .when('/', { title: 'Transactions', templateUrl: 'partials/transaction.view.html', controller: TransactionCtrl })
        .when('/about', { title: 'About', templateUrl: 'partials/about.view.html', controller: AboutCtrl })
        .when('/transaction', { title: 'Transactions', templateUrl: 'partials/transaction.view.html', controller: TransactionCtrl })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}])
```

Here's the controllers. I can hit a breakpoint in `AboutCtrl` but not in the other one. I added `TransactionCtrl.$inject` recently to see if that would help but there isn't a difference:

```
 function TransactionCtrl($scope, $location, logger, ngGrid) {
    logger.log("in TransactionCtrl");

    $scope.transactionList =
         [
                    { TransactionID: 1, Title: "TuElectric", Category: "Expense", Amount: "$  76.80", Date: "Jan 1" },
                    { TransactionID: 2, Title: "QT", Category: "Expense", Amount: "$   62.38", Date: "Jan 1" },
                    { TransactionID: 3, Title: "Kroger", Category: "Expense", Amount: "$  123.67", Date: "Jan 3" },
                    { TransactionID: 4, Title: "All State", Category: "Expense", Amount: "$  248.17", Date: "Jan 3" },
                    { TransactionID: 5, Title: "Credit Union", Category: "Income", Amount: "$1,897.00", Date: "Jan 4" }
         ];

    $scope.error = "";

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: "transactionList"
        //, showGroupPanel: true
    };


}
    TransactionCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', 'logger', 'ngGrid'];

    function AboutCtrl($scope, logger) {
        $scope.logEntries = logger.logEntries;
}
```

The partial view:

```
    <!-- Transaction page partial view -->
<div style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left:2em;">
<a href="#/about" class="pageLink">About</a> 
</div>  

<p class="error" data-ng-show="error.length">{{error}}</p>
<br/>
<article>
    <header>
        <h2>Transaction List</h2>
    </header>

    <p>(trnx view) 1 + 2 = {{ 1 + 2 }}</p>
    <ul id="fauxTable">
        <li>
            <p><span>Title</span><span>Category</span><span>Amount</span><span>Date</span></p>
        </li>
        <li data-ng-repeat="item in transactionList">
           <p><span>{{item.Title}}</span><span>{{item.Category}}</span><span>{{item.Amount}}</span><span>{{item.Date}}</span></p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</article>   

<article>
    <h2>Transaction List (ngGrid)</h2>
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions">

    </div>

</article>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @rGil Aha yes, "Unknown provider: ngGridProvider <- ngGridundefined". Damn it. I removed references to this library and all is working as expected. http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/ Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about missing library